# Oracle PL/SQL code conventions

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I am curious, is there any offcial code guidlines or conventions for code formatting in Oracle PL/SQL?

Comment: Sorry, voted to close because if you ask 1,000 developers you'll get 1,001 opinions.

Comment: A bit of searching with Google suggests that Oracle has not published any official code style document. It looks like some book publishers (such as O'Reilley) have chapters in their books about code style, but I am not sure it's what you're looking for.

Comment: You can use code beautifier.

Comment: @DavidAldridge I also voted to close, but on second thought I wish I hadn't.  The question is only asking if there are "official" guidelines, which I believe has an objective answer - No.

Comment: I was going to answer this, but I decided it would make a better blog post.  http://radiofreetooting.blogspot.co.uk/2013/07/plsql-coding-standards-revisited.html

Comment: @jonearles And thank goodness for that, for who knows what monstrosities would be forced upon us?

Comment: I didn't ask for anybody's opinion, I've asked if there is an **official** convention. Now I know - there is not. Thats a pity, but, anyway, thank you all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there are no *official* guidelines or conventions.

Anything "official" would be in the [documentation](http://www.oracle.com/pls/db112/portal.all_books).  Other then a few random hints, I've never seen anything like this in any of the books.  Obviously I haven't read them all, but I also couldn't find anything in the [Master Index](http://www.oracle.com/pls/db112/show_mindex).  Oracle SQL Developer has a beautifier, but I've never seen anything to imply it's the official way to format code.

Comment: +1.  In fact the Oracle documentation uses a variety of conventions in the coding examples.  This is inevitable given how the manuals have evolved over the years.